# .htaccess - R=404 NOT Showing Custom Error Page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to show error page when a user access php files with `.php` extension. But this is not showing the custom error page I set. Instead it shows the default Apache error page.

```
# Run Php without filename extension
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Return 404 if original request is .php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# Error Pages
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
```

**Edit:** I know I can use `RewriteRule .* /error [L,R]` but I want to show error page keeping same URL. For example, if user visits /login.php, he must stay at /login.php, but this will redirect to /error.php.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to trigger the custom error document automatically. The `R=404` flag apparently induces Apache's default error page to be generated. Even the `PT`|`passthrough` has no effect on the error page handling.
(Tested on *Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) / Debian 4.9.135-1 (2018-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux*)

A viable solution would be to *rewrite* the path to the error handler file instead of performing a *redirect*, however, this will set the status code incorrectly to `200`.

```
RewriteRule  ^   error404.php    [END]
```

Both, `http_response_code()` and `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']` will be `200` *(int / string type)*. You need to set the status code within PHP on your own.

```
$previous_status = http_response_code(404);
```

If you plan to have a catch-all error handler, you could write a status to the environment which is mapped to the `$_SERVER` variable.

```
RewriteRule  ^   error.php       [E=INTENDED_STATUS:404,END]
```

In this case `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_INTENDED_STATUS']` will be `404`. I have tested to set `E=STATUS:404`, however, `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']` gets overwritten with `200`. A `'REDIRECT_'` prefix is prepended automatically by mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I was late to the question as just today I was having the same problem and researching another problem I have, I found the solution to this problem.

All you have to do is put a condition before the rule (in your case a second condition):

```
RewriteCond% {ENV: REDIRECT_STATUS} ^ $
```

That would be all

My code for the same problem as yours is as follows:

```
RewriteCond% {ENV: REDIRECT_STATUS} ^ $
RewriteRule ^ (. *) \. Php $ - [R = 404, L]
```

The explanation is that the condition prevents a loop from being created (hence the default error). As we are redirecting all direct access to some php file towards the 404 error which is in turn a php file, the condition prevents the loop from being created, since it checks whether or not there is a redirection to the file.

Sorry for the language, but I hardly speak it.

Greetings